# different outputs for checking if a nan value is in the list or not

Tags: python, numpy

I have a list and I want to check if there is a missing value or not! I used two different ways to check it but didn't get the same outputs!

```
np.nan in lst1
```

output for this one is "False"

```
n = 0
for i in range(len(lst1)):
    if lst1[i] is np.nan :
        n+=1
print(n)
```

and for this one is 1!

the second answer  is actually true but I don't know why in the first code I got "False"

Comment: Can you post the contents of `lst1`?

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem - you have to show `lst1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use math.isnan(x) is preferred way of NaN finding. As I understand np.nan and pure python NaN are not the same objects. And you get False at checking.

```
import math
import numpy as np

lst1 = [1,2,3, float('nan'), 2, np.nan, 4]
for ix, vl in enumerate(lst1):
    if math.isnan(vl):
        print(ix, vl)

for ix, vl in enumerate(lst1):
    if vl is np.nan:
        print(ix, vl)
```

Output for math.isnan()

```
3 nan
5 nan
```

Output for np.nan check

```
5 nan
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what your `lst1` looks like so I created my own and ran the examples above.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> lst1 = [1,2,3, np.nan, 2,3,4]
>>> np.nan in lst1
True
```

The function `isin()` can be looked at in the documentation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html). This function looks to see if the element is contained in the list and will return `True` if it is. Without the original list you used, it is hard to determine how you got `False`.

I also ran the second portion of code you shared to make sure I was getting the same result, and I received 1 as the output there for the list I provided.

```
>>> for i in range(len(lst1)):
...     if lst1[i] is np.nan :
...         n+=1
... 
>>> print(n)
1
```

If you can provide your original list, that may be helpful to determine what the problem is.